# My website was working fine suddenly when i ran it next day it was showing error how can i fix this error

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WpOrg\Requests\Hooks' not found in /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-settings.php(245): require() #1 /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-config.php(101): require_once('/home/greeting/...') #2 /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/greeting/...') #3 /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/greeting/...') #4 /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/greeting/...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php on line 18

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/greeting/public_html/rajpootinternationals.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835

I have also tried renaming the plugins folder but that error is not resolved. My website page opens but when I click on a link or a page it shows this error.

Comment: It's very likely this is due to a change in the code deployed to your website. I doubt it was "sudden" but rather the result of a change someone made.

Answer (score -1):

Such problems come from many reasons:

- Maybe you left the automatic update and some plugins or theme were updated and your site remained on the old version of WordPress.
- One of them is that during the update, some files are "lost" if the update is suddenly interrupted during operation.
- File permissions can affect this as well but this is the least likely, unless the server has some malware.
- Speaking of malware, it's also possible that someone hacked the site and cracked the code.

My suggestion is to restore the previous backup, turn off updates on live site, perform updates and checks on the development site, and put on the live site updated  working version.

Always update the WordPress core first and then slowly one plugin at a time and after each update go over the whole site again. It is a slow process and boring, but the only sure way to find what and who is causing you problems.

**On the live site, do not leave the display of PHP errors turned on because it is a big security problem.**

Comment: My website home page opens but when I click on a link or a page it shows this error.

Comment: Yes, because you are missing some file or some function inside themes and plugins is not properly called. If it worked until a few days ago, it means that someone or something changed the site. It's either a bad update or a hacker attack. I have stated above how to approach it.

Comment: what can I do now.

Comment: If you have a previous backup, restore it. If you don't have it then the problem is serious and you have to manually download and replace all plugins, theme, WordPress core via FTP or hire a professional to do it for you. But first of all, ask your hosting company for help. That's my suggestion.

Comment: My website is hosted on cPanel